# Can I change my Hero's name?

Tags: heroville

So I have some hero's that got lucky and got a lot of experience. I want to reward him with a change to the default name. Can this be done?

Comment: in-game... no, but there is a way to change it using the developer console, if that would be ok (it could be seen as cheating).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the name can not be changed via the game mechanics.

In the console however

```
var el = document.getElementById('wrap'); 
var ngEl = angular.element(el);
var scope = ngEl.scope();
scope.heroList[0].name;
```

repeat that changing the 0 until you find the name of the hero you are looking to change, then change that line to read

```
scope.heroList[0].name = "New hero name"
```

where the 0 is the number of the hero you discovered.